# How to solve the following exercise?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let $g:\left[0,\dfrac{π}{2}\right]\to \mathbb{R}$ be $$g(x) = \int_{\cos{x}}^{\sin{x}}\sqrt{1-t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t.$$

I need to find the value of $g'(x)$. Can you give me any hints how to do that?

If $G$ is a primitive of $g$, then $g(x)=G(\sin{x})-G(\cos{x})$, but I do not know if it is the right way or what to do after.

Comment: Check out the Leibnitz Integral Rule https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: @welshman500 That isn't necessary here. Just the fundamental theorem of calculus and the chain rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $F(x) = \int_0^x \sqrt{1 - t^2} \ dt$. Then $g(x) = F(\sin x) - F(\cos x)$ and so $g'(x) = F'(\sin x) \cos x + F'(\cos x) \sin x$. Noting that $F'(x) = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$ we obtain
$$ g'(x) = |\cos x| \cos x + |\sin x| \sin x. $$

Comment: Ok but how did you get this idea?

Comment: "we obtain $g'(x)=\ldots$" ...Which, on the interval $[0,\frac\pi2]$, is also $g'(x)=\ldots$

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with solving the trivial integral??

$$\int\sqrt{1 - t^2}\ dt = \frac{1}{2} \left(t \sqrt{1-t^2}+\sin ^{-1}(t)\right)$$

Hence just substitute $t = \cos(x)$ and $t = \sin(x)$ and thou hast

$$\frac{1}{2} \left(\sin ^{-1}(\sin (x))+\sin (x) \sqrt{\cos ^2(x)}-\sin ^{-1}(\cos (x))-\sqrt{\sin ^2(x)} \cos (x)\right)$$

Then take the easy derivative which gives you

$$g'(x) = \sin (x) \sqrt{\sin ^2(x)}+\cos (x) \sqrt{\cos ^2(x)}$$

The square roots, due to the chosen range, can be written as the modulus of the sine and cosine respectively.

Hence

$$g'(x) = \sin(x)|\sin(x)| + \cos(x)|\cos(x)|$$